# MATLAB Initial Objective Function Evaluation Error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a plot in MATLAB by iterating over values of a constant (A) with respect to a system of equations. My code is pasted below:

```
function F=Func1(X, A)

%X(1) is c
%X(2) is h 
%X(3) is lambda
%A is technology (some constant) 
%a is alpha

a=1;

F(1)=1/X(1)-X(3)

F(2)=X(3)*(X(1)-A*X(2)^a)

F(3)=-1/(24-X(2))-X(3)*A*a*X(2)^(a-1)
```

```
clear, clc

init_guess=[0,0,0]

for countA=1:0.01:10
    result(countA,:)=[countA,fsolve(@Func1, init_guess)] 
end


display('The Loop Has Ended') 
display(result) 
%plot(result(:,1),result(:,2))
```

The first set of code, I am defining the set of equations I am attempting to solve. In the second set of lines, I am trying to write a loop which iterates through the values of A that I want, [1,10] with an increment of 0.01. Right now, I am just trying to get my loop code to work, but I keep on getting this error:

"Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue."

I am not sure why this is the case. From what I understand, this is the result of my initial guess matrix not being the right size, but I believe it should be of size 3, as I am solving for three variables. Additionally, I'm fairly confident there's nothing wrong with how I'm referencing my Func1 code in my Loop code.

Any advice you all could provide would be sincerely appreciated. I've only been working on MATLAB for a few days, so if this is a rather trivial fix, pardon my ignorance. Thanks.

Comment: Is `A` a known constant?

Comment: I am trying to solve my system of equations given each value of A between [1,10] and graph the results, so yes, A is a known constant.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you should use something like `fsolve(@(X) Func1(X,A), init_guess)` for each value of `A`. Complete code in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues with your code:

`1/X(1)` in function `Func1` is prone to the division by zero miscalculations. I would change it to `1/(X(1)+eps)`.

If `countA` is incrementing by 0.01, it cannot be used as an index for `result`. Perhaps introduce an index `ind` to increment.

I have included your constant `A` within the function to clarify what optimization variables are.

Here is the updated code. I don't know if the results are reasonable or not:

```
init_guess=[0,0,0];

ind = 1;
for countA=1:0.01:10
    result(ind,:)=[countA, fsolve(@(X) Func1(X,countA), init_guess)];
    ind = ind+1;
end

display('The Loop Has Ended')
display(result) 
%plot(result(:,1),result(:,2))

function F=Func1(X,A)

%X(1) is c
%X(2) is h 
%X(3) is lambda
%A is technology (some constant) 
%a is alpha

a=1;

F(1)=1/(X(1)+eps)-X(3);

F(2)=X(3)*(X(1)-A*X(2)^a);

F(3)=-1/(24-X(2))-X(3)*A*a*X(2)^(a-1);

end
```

Comment: vote +1 for the anonymous function handle and the increment error. Please split the code block or wrap the scripting part into a function that it is indeed a valid file in MATLAB ;)

Comment: @max : It is indeed a valid file in its current format as long as your MATLAB version is equal to or greater than R2016b, please see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html). Been tested on my MATLAB too!

Comment: @RealReza wow, I didn't know this. Nested functions in a script.... (BTW you defined the function `Func1` to take only a single argument but when defining anonymous function handle you provide two)